# EV3 Home edition for Mac missing import block option

Tags: ev3

I'm running EV3 HE 1.3.1 on macOS Sierra 10.12.6, and I'm unable to import the ultrasonic sensor.

When I open tools -> import block -> browse, the open button is always disabled, it does not allow me to select any folder.

Is there a command line utility to import the blocks perhaps?

Stuck on this for a while now.

Comment: Do you have a project open when you are doing this? Many of the menu items are disabled unless you have a project open.

Comment: I do, and it's not the tools -> import that is disabled, I can actually get to the import screen, however the open dialog from mac shows greyed files not allowing me to select anything

Comment: It is working for me. Make sure your files have the .ev3b file extension. These are the only files that can be selected.

Comment: They have the proper extension, something is wrong with this install. I tried on a different mac machine and it's working. Not sure what else I can do. I'm asking support to see if they have any ideas (I have already uninstalled and installed it again with no luck) Thank you